# Proving that elements in the domain of a function always appear in the range of that function

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

Given any set $A$, and any function $f$ whose domain is $A$, show that the set
{${x \in A \ | \ x \notin f(x)}$} is not in the range of $f$ (i.e. there is no $a \in A$ such that
$f(a)$ = {${x ∈ A \ | \ x \notin f(x)}$}).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The range is always a subset of the domain?  What about $f:\mathbf{N}\to\mathbf{R}$ defined by $f(n)=n+1/2?$

Comment: Fair point. I've misunderstood the question, then. "There is no $a \in A$ such that $f(a)$ = {${x ∈ A \ | \ x \notin f(x)}$". What is the correct reading here?

Comment: It's hard to put in words in a natural manner.  It's something like, "No element is mapped to the set of all elements of the domain that do not belong to their images."

Comment: Your "put more colloquially" version doesn't mean the same as the question, but your immediately preceding, parenthetical version is correct: There is no $a\in A$ such that $f(a)=\{x\in A\mid x\notin f(x)\}$. Now if you use the definition of the set notation $\{x\in A\mid x\notin f(x)\}$, you'll find the following equivalent formulation of the problem: There is no $a\in A$ such that, for all $x$, $x\in f(a)$ if and only if $x\in  A$ and $x\notin f(x)$. To prove that, suppose there were such an $a$ and consider the "for all $x$" statement in the special case $x=a$.

Comment: Without including the codomain, your question resorts to what to what the heck are you talking about.

Comment: The input of the identity function  always appears in the range.

Comment: To echo the comments of William above: It seems that $f$ is a set-valued function.  For your question to be understood, it should be clarified what the domain and range of $f$ are. (I have no idea how people can "answer" the question in its current ambiguous form...in fact doing so validates the practice of asking an ambiguous question). Is it the case that $f: A\rightarrow 2^A$?  (where $2^A$ is the set of all subsets of $A$)

Comment: @saulspatz as fleablood pointed out below, we have to assume $f(x)$ maps to $P(A)$. So maybe the question is as follows: show there is no $a \in A$ such that $f(x)$ maps that element to a subset of $A$ of which $a$ is not an element.

Comment: @Michael Yes, that must be the case.

Answer (score 1):

====

I think there needs to be a little bit more to the question than you are stating [*].

$A$ is a set and $f$ is a function with $A$ as a domain.  SO $f: A\to ?????$ what?  What set is the codomain?  What is the output of the function.  It does not say.

I'd read this as $f$ *could* be any function and it could map to any set $X$ so $f: A \to X$ but we are not given any information of what $X$ may be.

But then they talk of $\{x \in A \ | \ x \notin f(x)\}$.  But in general this doesn't make sense.  $f(x)$ is in general not a set but a single element of $X$.  So that implies $X$ is a set of sets.  And it is a set of sets which will share some of the same elements of $A$.

This in not a typical function $f:A \to ????$.

This strongly implies $f$ is a function that maps the elements of $A$ to subsets of $A$.  i.e. $f:A \to P(A)$ where for some $x \in A$ then $f(x)$ is a subset of $A$.

If *that* is the case then $S = \{x\in A| x \not \in f(x)\}$ or $S$ is the set of all $x \in A$ that get mapped to subset of $A$ that do not happen to have $x$ as element.

So for example:  if $A = \{1,2,3\}$ and $f:\{1,2,3\} \to \{\emptyset, \{1\},\{2\},\{3\},\{1,2\},\{2,3\},\{1,3\}, \{1,2,3\}\}$.  And $f(2) = \{1,2\}$ then $2 \in \{1,2\}= f(2)$.  So $2 \not \in S$.  But if  $f(1) = \{2,3\}$ then $1 \not \in \{2,3\} = f(1)$ so $1 \not \in f(1)$ so $1 \in S$.

So they are asking you prove that there is no $a\in A$ so that $f(a) = S$.

And this is ... the liar's paradox.

If $f(a) = S$ then either $a \in S$ or $a \not \in S$.  If $a \in S$ then $a \not \in f(a) = S$.  That is a contradiction.  But of $a \not\in S = f(a)$ then $a \in S$.  That is a contradiction.

To put this in English (see if this makes sense; it can get confusing):

Let $f$ be a function that maps elements of a set $A$ to subsets of $A$.  If we take the set of all elements that that are not elements of the subsets they are mapped to, then there is no element that is mapped to that set. That would cause a logical inconsistency as the element that maps to such a set would be an element of the set it was mapped to if and only if it were not.

===

By the way; paradox resolution:   So the liars paradox or Russel's paradox says.  Define $f(k) : = S := \{x\in A|x \not \in f(x)\}$.  We can't define that set $S$ until *after* we define $f$ and $S$ relies upon $f$ in its definition.  As such it simply will not be any $f(x)$ and such a command is simply not possible.

[*]===== Perhaps more general and set theoretical ====

[*] Or maybe not.

Henning Makholm  says in a comment that this is probably is a set theory context in which every object is in some way viewed as being a set.

So if $f: \mathbb N \to \mathbb Z$ via $f(x) = x^2 - 2$ and so $f(2) = 2$ then $2$ is not merely the natural number $2$ but a set as well.  As $2 \not \in $ the  set we represent as $2 = \{0, 1\} = \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}$ so $2 \in$ the mystery set.  but $f(3) = 7$ and $7 = \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ and $3\in \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\} = 7 = f(3)$ so $3$ is not in the mystery set.

In fact I think for *this* $f$ the mystery set is $\{0,1,2\}= 3$ and there is no $n$ so that $f(n) =3$.  (I might be wrong about that.)

.... (redo of above)....

Perhaps a practical way to see this.

In set theoretical terms the natural numbers when viewed as sets are:

$0 = \emptyset$ and

For $n > 0$ then $n = (n-1)\cup \{n-1\} = \{0,1,2,3,......, n-1\}$.

So if $f:\mathbb N \to \mathbb N: f(n)=n^2 - 4n +4=(n-2)^2$.  Then $f(0) = 0$ and $0 =\emptyset \not \in \emptyset = 0$ so $0 \not \in f(0)$ so $0 \in S$.

$f(1) = 1$ and $1 = \{0\}$ and $1\not \in \{0\} =1 = f(1)$ so $1 \in S$.

$f(2) = 0$ and $2 \not \in 0= f(2)$ so $2 \in S$.

$f(3) = 1$ and $3 \not \in 1 = f(3)$ so $3 \in S$.

$f(4) = 4$ and $4 \not in 4 = \{0,1,2,3\}$ so $4 \in S$.

For $n\ge 5$ then $f(n) = (n-2)^2 > n$ and $n  \in x$ for any $x > n$ so $n \not \in S$.

So $S = \{0,1,2,3,4\} = 5$.  And $5 \ne f(n)$ for any $n$.

That's kind of neat.

Comment: I think all this probably happens in a purely set theoretic context, such that $f(a)$ is a set simply because everything is a set in that context. And then $a$ may or may not be an element of that set.

Comment: That could be true.  But I think for someone "new to functions and am having difficulty with the following question" should have the premise of ... what the heck we are talking about the universe we live in implies... explained to them.  Too often students get confused because "now that we are working in abstracts we needn't explain but in abstracts" gets just incomprehensible.

Comment: I agree that what the OP is reading is probably unnecessarily confusing at his level.

Comment: I am giving a "+1" based on the first 2-3 sentences, ending in $f:A\rightarrow ?????$. I did not read the rest.

Comment: @fleablood by the way, absolutely extraordinary answer. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

A function $f$ is just a set of ordered pairs (of sets; everything is a set) (which means $\forall x \in f: \exists a,b: x = (a,b)$) , with the special  "functional" property that $\forall x,x',y : ((x,y) \in f \land (x,y')) \in f \to y=y'$.

The domain of $f$ is just the set $\operatorname{dom}(f) := \{x: \exists y: (x,y) \in f\}$, the set of all $x$ that are used as "input". The range of $f$ is just $\operatorname{ran}(f):=\{y: \exists x: (x,y) \in f\}$, all sets that occur as "values".

Now suppose $\operatorname{dom}(f) = A$ and define $A'= \{x \in A: x \notin f(x)\}$
which is a well-defined set, by the axiom of separation.

Suppose $A'$ is in the range of $f$, so that $\exists x: (x,A') \in f$.
The fact that $(x,A') \in f$ implies that $x \in \operatorname{dom}(f)=A$ and also that $f(x) = A'$.

And by definition of $A'$: $$x \in A' \text{ iff } x \notin f(x) = A'$$

which is a contradiction. 
So $A' \notin \operatorname{ran}(f)$, as claimed.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The question is about functions $f \colon A \to \mathcal{P}(A)$. That is, functions with domain $A$ such that, for every $t\in A$, the output $f(t)$ is a subset of $A$. [For example, $f \colon \mathbb{N} \to \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$, $f(n) = $ set of divisors of $n$. In this case $f(4) = \{1, 2, 4\}$.]

Let $B = \{x \in A \mid x\not\in f(x)\} \subset A$, hence $B \in \mathcal{P}(A)$. Suppose that $B$ were in the image of $f$ and let $a\in A$ such that $f(a) = B$. Show that both $a\in B$ and $a\not\in B$ lead to contradictions.

Added: This is a formal presentation of the Barber paradox (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barber_paradox).

More precisely, suppose we are talking about people on an island (close system). For every person $x$, let $f(x)$ be the set of people shaved by $x$ (may include $x$ or not). Then $B$ is the set of people who do not shave themselves. Is there any person who shaves exactly those people who do not shave themselves? Does that person shave itself?

Comment: I think I am following. It helps me to rephrase the problem a bit more casually. Perhaps we can say the image of $f$ is the relevant output of $f$. It seems like $a\in B$ is saying that an element in domain of $f$, ie $A$, is also an element in the output of that function. Why is this a contradiction?

Comment: $a \in B$ means that, by the property that defines $B$, $a\not\in f(a) = B$.

Comment: Why is the codomain $\mathcal{P}(A)$?

Comment: @Hurkyl How else would you make sense of $x \in f(x)$ or $x\not\in f(x)$?

Comment: @CatalinZara: A typical way is that in a material set theory, we can typically ask $x \in S$ for *any* $x$ and *any* set $S$. In a pure version like ZFC which is typically used for foundations, everything is a set anyways, so $x \in y$ is a meaningful proposition for *any* two objects.

Answer (score 0):

**Cantor's theorem** states

> Let $A$ be a set. There is no bijective correspondence between $A$ and $\mathcal P(A)$.

where $\mathcal P(A)$ is the *power set* of $A$, that is, the set of all subsets of $A$.

What you're looking at is the trick that lies at the heart of the proof of this theorem. For some reason the author of what you're reading decided to strip away all the assumptions that are not necessary to prove that the trick *works* (though they *are* necessary to get any intuitive idea of what the point of it is).

With more assumptions in it, the trick would be

> Let $A$ be a set, and let $f$ be a function $A\to\mathcal P(A)$. Then there is an element of $\mathcal P(A)$ (that is, a subset of $A$) that is not in the range of $f$.
>
> In other words, $f$ is not surjective, and in particular is not a bijection.

And the proof of that would be what you have there -- namely that one subset of $A$ that is guaranteed not to be in the range of $f$ is just $\{x\in A\mid x\notin f(x)\}$.

It turns out that it's not necessary for this argument to know that $f(x)$ is always a subset of $A$. In fact, if there's some $x$ such that $f(x)$ is *not* a subset of $A$, then this $x$ is no danger for our conclusion that such-and-such subset of $A$ is not in the range of $f$.

Since we're (apparently) working in pure set theory so everything is a set, we can still ask *whether* $x$ is in $f(x)$ even when $f$ is not a subset of $A$. The answer can be yes or no, but what it is happens not to matter for the conclusion.

It would be a lot *clearer*, however, if the author had specified that $f$ was $A\to\mathcal P(A)$ instead of just some function with domain $A$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $f(a) = \{ x \in A \mid x \notin f(x) \}$.

What can you say about the proposition $a \in f(a)$?

---

> Now, intuitively, I see that since the range is always a subset of the domain,

This is very much not true in general for functions.